# Need a Solution for the Type Mismatch Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to loop through all cells in a given range through for each loop.

The code runs one time but after that gives a runtime error 1004, Application Defined or Object-Defined Error

Below is the Code Block that I am having problem with:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim wbInstallation As String

wbInstallation = Application.Workbooks(2).Name
'Debug.Print wbInstallation.Name

For Each cell In Workbooks(wbInstallation).Sheets(wsName).Range(Cells(Start_Row_Num, Start_Column_Num), _
                        Cells(Last_Row_Num, Last_Column_Num))
                    If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(204, 0, 0) Then
                        Workbooks(2).Sheets(wsName).Range(Cells(cell.Row, 1), Cells(cell.Row, Last_Column_Num)).Copy
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName).Range("A8").PasteSpecial
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    End If
Next
```

I tried it in a different way but it gave me a Type Mismatch Error, Runtime Error 13. Following is the code:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim wbInstallation As Workbook


Set wbInstallation = Application.Workbooks(2)
'Debug.Print wbInstallation.Name

For Each cell In Workbooks(wbInstallation).Sheets(wsName).Range(Cells(Start_Row_Num, Start_Column_Num), _
                        Cells(Last_Row_Num, Last_Column_Num))
                    If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(204, 0, 0) Then
                        Workbooks(2).Sheets(wsName).Range(Cells(cell.Row, 1), Cells(cell.Row, Last_Column_Num)).Copy
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName).Range("A8").PasteSpecial
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    End If
Next
```

Kindly Help!

Comment: Cells always refer to the ActiveSheet!

Comment: You need to tell us *which* line triggers the error. We can't replicate your environment so we can't just run the code to figure it out...

Comment: Line 4 triggers the error. Start of the For Each Loop. Rest of the row and column variables have valid values.

Comment: As said above `Workbooks(wbInstallation).Sheets(wsName).Range(Cells(Start_Row_Num, Start_Column_Num), _
                        Cells(Last_Row_Num, Last_Column_Num))` is not valid

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference correct sheet in your code, i.e. give refernces to workbook and sheet when referencing to cells. See below:

```
For Each cell In Workbooks(wbInstallation).Worksheets (wsName).Range(Cells(Start_Row_Num, Start_Column_Num), _
  Cells(Last_Row_Num, Last_Column_Num))
```

change to:

```
For Each cell In Workbooks(wbInstallation).Worksheets(wsName).Range( _
  Workbooks(wbInstallation).Worksheets(wsName).Cells(Start_Row_Num, Start_Column_Num), _
  Workbooks(wbInstallation).Sheets(wsName).Cells(Last_Row_Num, Last_Column_Num))
```

and this:

```
Workbooks(2).Sheets(wsName).Range(Cells(cell.Row, 1), Cells(cell.Row, Last_Column_Num)).Copy
```

to this:

```
Workbooks(2).Sheets(wsName).Range( _
  Workbooks(2).Worksheets(wsName).Cells(cell.Row, 1), _
  Workbooks(2).Worksheets(wsName).Cells(cell.Row, Last_Column_Num)
).Copy
```

This looks ugly, so I would recommend you storing references to particular sheets in a variable, like:

```
Dim s As Worksheets
Set sheet = 'sheet assignment
```

Comment: Made the changes which you suggested. The same line is now giving Runtime Error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: @ShashankBanerjee Do you have charts? `Workbook.Sheets` is not limited to returning Worksheets. You should be using `Workbook.Worksheets` instead.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Tried the updated answer. Still getting a type mismatch error.  [link]https://photos.app.goo.gl/m1dyBGEtn2npdrA26  Snapshot of the updated code. I have charts in the workbook but on a separate sheet. Variable (wsName) is extracted by looping through all the sheets and storing there names in this variable if only the sheet names match with the sheet names on my report. So, I think that the sheet containing charts should not be included.